# "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()" when using pusher with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, debugging, pusher

I have implemented a very basic and by-the-tutorial Pusher triggers in my django app.
At first it worked great, but after a few commits I ran into the following exception:

```
"object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"
```

Out of the second of the following lines:

```
p = pusher.Pusher()
p[page_key].trigger('page_update', {'msgid' : message.id})
```

Different or an empty dict produced same result, same as changing page_key to string instead of unicode - nothing.
Also note that type() of p and p.trigger gives logical results, and they're definitely not None.

This line WORKS IN SOME CASES (which I have no clue what so special about them) and has worked in the past as I've mentioned, yet I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

It seems that none of the last commits have anything to do with Pusher, so I'm helpless. Searching the web for this exception wasn't fruitful  at all and in general there's not enough documentation regarding to django + Pusher.

It is probably something else that I'm doing wrong but I have no clue where to start looking.

Any help will be most appreciated.

```
Traceback:

  79.         p[page_key].trigger('page_update', {'msgid' : message.id})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pusher/__init__.py" in trigger
  41.         status = self.send_request(self.signed_query(event, json_data, socket_id), json_data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pusher/__init__.py" in signed_query
  54.         signature = hmac.new(self.pusher.secret, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py" in new
  133.     return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py" in __init__
  68.         if len(key) > blocksize:

Exception Type: TypeError at /sphere/comment
Exception Value: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Post the traceback, so we can see where the error occurs, not just the line in your code that triggers it.

Comment: Add `DEBUG = True` to the top of your Django settings file and let the error propagate, or else do `except WhateverException, e: print e, sys.exc_info()[2]`

Comment: DEBUG = True is in my settings.py by default. as for your second suggestion it produce: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() <traceback object at 0xa00cfa4> ###how do I print the error itself and not its object?

Comment: If you're in debug mode, you should get a whole huge page describing the error, with local variables at each stack frame, etc. when you have an exception, and the full traceback should be in the server log

Comment: I'm sorry, here's the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.pusher.secret is None there instead of a string.  Are your settings for pusher not getting picked up?

Comment: I have a set_pusher() function that wasn't invoked in all cases. Thanks.

Comment: Doing the same thing in Flask. The hidden environment variables were not being loaded. Your answer gave me a clue and I have been able to fix it using the `python-dotenv` package